# Фризы при изменении размеров окна JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь сделать с помощь JavaFX прозрачное не декарированное окно с изменяемыми размерами, как у обычных окон. Столкнулся с проблемой, при изменении размеров этого окна наблюдаются фризы, дрожания, контент окна не сразу принимает изменения.

Ниже минимальный рабочий код в котором показан применяемый мною способ, правая панель borderPaneR не сразу принимает изменения, трясется, фризит при изменении размеров. С левой кстати все в порядке. Может подскажете как этого можно избежать.

```
    public class DemoBehaviorProblem extends Application {
    double initX;
    double windowX;
    double windowWidth;
    final int BORDER_WIDTH = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Создаем элементы окна
        Pane borderPaneL = new Pane();
        borderPaneL.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(85, 255, 0, 0.5); -fx-cursor: w-resize;");
        Pane borderPaneR = new Pane();
        borderPaneR.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(85, 255, 0, 0.5); -fx-cursor: e-resize;");
        Pane root = new Pane(borderPaneL, borderPaneR);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.5));

        // Настраиваем боковые панели
        borderPaneL.setPrefWidth(BORDER_WIDTH);
        borderPaneL.setPrefHeight(scene.getHeight());

        borderPaneR.setLayoutX(scene.getWidth() - BORDER_WIDTH);
        borderPaneR.setPrefWidth(BORDER_WIDTH);
        borderPaneR.setPrefHeight(scene.getHeight());

        //Контент окна
        VBox content = new VBox();
        content.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 230, 0, 0.5); -fx-pref-width: 336; -fx-pref-height: 284;");
        content.setLayoutX(BORDER_WIDTH * 4);
        content.setLayoutY(BORDER_WIDTH);
        root.widthProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> content.setPrefWidth(newValue.doubleValue() - 8*BORDER_WIDTH)));
        root.getChildren().add(content);

        // Показываем резултат
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // Настраиваем поведение resizable

        // При изменении ширины окна менять положение правой понели
        stage.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> borderPaneR.setLayoutX(newValue.doubleValue() - BORDER_WIDTH));

        // Передвигаем левый край окна
        borderPaneL.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {
            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                initX = event.getScreenX();
                windowX = stage.getX();
                windowWidth = windowX + stage.getWidth();
            }

            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                double deltaX = event.getScreenX() - initX;
                stage.setX(windowX + deltaX);
                stage.setWidth(windowWidth - windowX - deltaX);
            }
        });

        // Передвигаем правый край окна
        borderPaneR.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {
            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                initX = event.getSceneX();
                windowWidth = stage.getWidth();
            }

            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                double deltaX = event.getSceneX() - initX;
                stage.setWidth(windowWidth + deltaX);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, на данный момент JavaFx не умеет объединять события изменения координаты окна, его размеров и рисования сцены (смотрю исходники к 8 версии).

Поэтому, при перемещении левой границы, на экране виден результат рендера после `stage.setX()`, затем после `stage.setWidth()` и только потом - отрисовка сцены.

Чтобы хоть как-то обойти эту проблему можно воспользоваться тем фактом, что JavaFx умеет объединять события рисования: если создать промежуточную полностью прозрачную панель (`Pane`) размером с экран, и в нее поместить ту панель, которая сейчас зовется root, то после этого, при перемещении левой границы, правая будет стоять как влитая.

Получается как-то так:

```
package frizes;

import com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class DemoBehaviorProblem extends Application {
    double initX;
    double windowX;
    double windowWidth;
    final int BORDER_WIDTH = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Создаем элементы окна
        Pane borderPaneL = new Pane();
        borderPaneL.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(85, 255, 0, 0.5); -fx-cursor: w-resize;");
        Pane borderPaneR = new Pane();
        borderPaneR.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(85, 255, 0, 0.5); -fx-cursor: e-resize;");
        Pane root = new Pane(borderPaneL, borderPaneR);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);");
        root.setPrefWidth(400);
        root.setPrefHeight(300);
        Pane superroot = new Pane(root);
        Scene scene = new Scene(superroot ,
                Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth(), Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight(),
                new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

        root.setLayoutX((scene.getWidth()-root.getPrefWidth())/2);
        root.setLayoutY((scene.getHeight()-root.getPrefHeight())/3);


        // Настраиваем боковые панели
        borderPaneL.setPrefWidth(BORDER_WIDTH);
        borderPaneL.setPrefHeight(root.getPrefHeight());

        borderPaneR.setLayoutX(root.getPrefWidth() - BORDER_WIDTH);
        borderPaneR.setPrefWidth(BORDER_WIDTH);
        borderPaneR.setPrefHeight(root.getPrefHeight());

        //Контент окна
        VBox content = new VBox();
        content.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 230, 0, 0.5); -fx-pref-width: 336; -fx-pref-height: 284;");
        content.setLayoutX(BORDER_WIDTH * 4);
        content.setLayoutY(BORDER_WIDTH);
        root.prefWidthProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> content.setPrefWidth(newValue.doubleValue() - 8*BORDER_WIDTH)));
        root.getChildren().add(content);

        // Показываем резултат
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // Настраиваем поведение resizable

        // При изменении ширины окна менять положение правой понели
        root.prefWidthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println(observable +" "+ oldValue+" "+ newValue);
            borderPaneR.setLayoutX(newValue.doubleValue() - BORDER_WIDTH);
        });

        // Передвигаем левый край окна
        borderPaneL.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {

            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                initX = event.getScreenX();
                windowX = root.getLayoutX();
                windowWidth = windowX + root.getWidth();
            }

            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                double deltaX = event.getScreenX() - initX;
                double newWidth = windowWidth - windowX - deltaX;
                double newX = windowX + deltaX;
                root.setPrefWidth(newWidth);
                root.setLayoutX(newX);
            }
        });

        // Передвигаем правый край окна
        borderPaneR.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {
            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                initX = event.getSceneX();
                windowWidth = root.getWidth();
            }

            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                double deltaX = event.getSceneX() - initX;
                double newWidth = windowWidth + deltaX;
                root.setPrefWidth(windowWidth + deltaX);
                borderPaneR.setLayoutX(newWidth - BORDER_WIDTH);
                content.setPrefWidth(newWidth - 8 * BORDER_WIDTH);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Минус этого кода в том, что дальше основного монитора поле отображаться не будет.

Другой способ - просто отказаться от перемещения левой границы окна.

В JavaFx имеется пара вспомогательных методов для недекорированных окон, которые позволяют пользователю только либо перемещать окно за верхнюю часть,
 либо изменять размеры окна за правый нижний угол:

```
...
stage.show();

// За верхнюю часть высотой 22 можно перемещать окно:
com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).setUndecoratedMoveRectangle(22);

// За правый нижний квадрат 33х33 можно изменять размеры окна:
com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).setUndecoratedResizeRectangle(33);
```